# Slideshow/Gallery plugin based on WP Core Gallery

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, gallery

Looking for a plugin that I can hardcode into my custom post type template that pulls the images from gallery images added into the standard WP gallery.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code in my [answer to a similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/integrating-nextgen-gallery-with-gallerific/13974#13974).  It strips out and reworks the gallery shortcode to use with jQuery Gallerific.

Comment: Thanks - I also found two plugins that work as well. Easy Nivo Slider and Graph Paper Press's gallery option.

Comment: but I'll take a look at your method - Easy Nivo Slider is buggy, and the other creates a new custom post type which I'm not looking for.

Comment: @Jason that plugin is pretty rough and could easily be improved. If you use it check the html output of the images and it could easily be applied to cycle or something less complicated as gallerific.

Comment: i did find one that works well, so far. Ycyclista. Using Jquery cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I reworked a classipress theme gallery to use WP gallery and integrated it with Galleria for nice effect, the only problem i came across was that i needed a huge block of code to remove the WP Gallery styling and replace with my own so that Galleria would look sweet

Answer (score -2):

Hope this can help a year later :) http://helpforwp.com/plugins/custom-post-wp-gallery

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.